# Closing Multiple Modals using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Testing multiple modals on a site. Both modals will open fine. However, the second modal (contmodal) will not close. Also this seems to create an issue causing other JS to break.

```
//* Get the Newsletter Modal
var newsmodal = document.getElementById('newsletter-modal');
var contmodal = document.getElementById('contact-modal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var newsbtn = document.getElementsByClassName("signup-button")[0];
var editbtn = document.getElementsByClassName("contact-button")[0];

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var modalspan = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
newsbtn.onclick = function() {
    newsmodal.style.display = "block";
}
editbtn.onclick = function() {
    contmodal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
modalspan.onclick = function() {
    newsmodal.style.display = "none";
    contmodal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == newsmodal) {
        newsmodal.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == contmodal) {
        contmodal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: code seems with no issues. have you seen if there any errors in console?

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/EasonWang01/react-pure-css-modal

no need to using js

Comment: where is the problem  When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal? or  When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it??

Comment: If only the "newsletter-modal" is present neither the <span>(X) or outside the modal will close.

If both "newsletter-modal" and "contact-modal" is present then "newsletter-modal" works 100%. However, "contact-modal" will not close by clicking the <span>(x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. 
Here's this example you should refer to - http://jsfiddle.net/3Vykc/

```
<a href="#openModal1">Box 1</a>
<div id="openModal1" class="modalDialog">
<div>
   <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
   <h2>Modal Box 1</h2>
   <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.    </p>
   <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
</div>
</div>
<a href="#openModal2">Box 2</a>

<div id="openModal2" class="modalDialog">
<div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <h2>Modal Box 2</h2>
    <p><strong>Box 2</strong></p>
    <p>yadda yadda</p>
</div>
```

More references:

[Using multiple modal dialogs in one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427926/using-multiple-modal-dialogs-in-one-page)

[How can I close multiple bootstrap modals with the close button on the last popped modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27865116/how-can-i-close-multiple-bootstrap-modals-with-the-close-button-on-the-last-popp)

Comment: This is a great example. I was able to add in JS to close the modal if a user clicks outside the div.

`//* Get the Newsletter Modal
var modal1 = document.getElementById('openModal1');
var modal2 = document.getElementById('openModal2');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal1) {
        modal1.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == modal2) {
        modal2.style.display = "none";
    }
}`

Unfortunately, this doesn't allow the user to click on it again to reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following javascript to Abhinav Ralhan's solution:

```
//* Get the Newsletter Modal 
var modal1 = document.getElementById('openModal1'); 
var modal2 = document.getElementById('openModal2'); 

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it 
window.onclick = function(event) { 
    if (event.target == modal1 || event.target == modal2) { 
    window.location.href = "#"+close;
  }
}
```